# How do I convert a String to an String Array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, readfile

I'm reading from a file using Scanner, and the text contains the following.

[8, 3, 8, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8]

This was originally an integer Array that I had to convert to a String to be able to write in the file. Now, I need to be able to read the file back into java, but I need to be able to add the individual numbers together, so I need to get this String back into an array. Any help? Here's what I have:

```
File f = new File("testfile.txt");  
try{
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f); 
    fw.write(Arrays.toString(array1)); 
    fw.close(); 
} catch(Exception ex){
    //Exception Ignored
}

Scanner file = new Scanner(f);       
System.out.println(file.nextLine());
```

This prints out the list of numbers, but in a string. I need to access the integers in an array in order to add them up. This is my first time posting, let me know if I messed anything up.

Comment: Split the just-now-read line based on 'comma' and parseInt?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to remove the square brackets, [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to split the `String` into an array, [String#trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) to remove the whitespace, and [Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to convert the `String`s into int values.

In Java 8 you can use the Stream API for this:

```
int[] values = Arrays.stream(string.substring(1, string.length() - 1)
                     .split(","))
                     .mapToInt(string -> Integer.parseInt(string.trim()))
                     .toArray();
```

For summing it, you can use the [IntStream#sum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) method instead of converting it to an array at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to read the `String` back in an `Array`, just use `Regex`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "[8, 3, 8, 2, 3, 4, 41, 4, 5, 8]";
    // The "\\d+" gets the digits out of the String
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(data);

    int sum = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Results:

> 86

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
String original = "[8, 3, 8, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8]";
String[] splitted = original.replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "").split(",");
for(String s : splitted) {
    ints.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
}
```

Comment: Mind spaces and square brackets.

Comment: But the concept is valid. For this, a downvote?

Comment: @Stewart, It wasn't actually me downvoting, but your answer is incomplete. While the concept is valid, you should at least describe the shortcomings of your solution, or better give a full solution.